# CPU overheating when uploading images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, load

The problem is simply that I wrote the code below to upload random text and images with the same name but the last number in names  changed, but this leads to an increase in the processor temperature,
here is the code :

```
let ctn=document.getElementById("y_main");
function mainCtn(str,i){
var post= `  <section class="y_post">
<article class="y_post_article">
<h3>${str}</h">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Enim error dolores nulla vero animi a ex perspiciatis repellendus neque 
doloremque! Dolor culpa odio ea, excepturi eaque in similique tempore earum!</p>
<img width="200px" src="image/postimage/img_post${i}.pn" alt="post img">
</article>
<section class="y_post_btn">
    <button class="post_lbtn"><img src="icon/check.svg" alt="chat" srcset=""></button>
    <button class="post_cobtn"><img src="icon/chat-square-text.svg" alt="chat" srcset=""></button>
    <button class="post_shbtn"><img src="icon/share.svg" alt="chat" srcset=""></button>
</section>
<div class="y_comment_block">
<button class="close_btn_comment">close</button>
<p class="text_comment"></p>
<div class="comment_tool">
<textarea name="" class="input_comment" cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="insert comment"></textarea>
<button class="btn_comment">add</button>
</div>
</div>
</section>`
return post;
}

let b=1;
setInterval(function () { if(b<12){
    ctn.innerHTML+=mainCtn(`#${b}`,b);b++;
}
    else{
        clearInterval(myInterval); 
      
    }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: What is the contents of `myInterval`? The function `clearInterval` expects an ID returned by the function `setInterval`.

Comment: This question requires more detail.  Why do you think the CPU is overheating or related to this code?  What is the average size of images?  Is caching disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Just like @KompjoeFriek mentioned you need the `setInterval` ID, not an id you hardcode.

```
let b =1
const myInterval = setInterval(function () {
  if(b<12){
    ctn.innerHTML+=mainCtn(`#${b}`,b);b++;
  } else{
    clearInterval(myInterval);   
  }
}, 2000);
```

This should work.